# Different typechecking in similar methods

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I ran into a problem I'm not sure how to deal with yet: I have **very similar methods**, that do a **different typecheck** depending on the call. 
Let me be specific:

I have (for example) two methods:

```
String getValue(ParameterKeys key, Class<String> valueClass);
Double getValue(ParameterKeys key, Class<Double> valueClass);
```

These methods would read from the database table containing the key-value pairs, and depending on what should the type of the value be, they would return it if its valid.

However this above example is not possible, because generics doesnt allow it, the compiler sees two identical method signatures with different return types.

Is there another way of achieving this other than creating different methods that do almost the same, like this:

```
Boolean getBooleanValue(ParameterKeys parameterKey);
Double getDoubleValue(ParameterKeys parameterKey);
```

If yes, what is the best practice in this case? How do I approach deciding between them?

Thank you very much for your time!